# Is there an efficient way to match two string columns in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to match two string columns and count number of (exact) matches.
For example, there are two columns like

```
index   col1   col2
0       aa     ji
1       bs     aa
2       qe     bs
3       gd     aa
```

col1 consists of unique ids. I want to count how many times each element of col1 occurs in col2. In other words, I would like to get an output like:

```
col3
2
1
0
0
```

in above example.

I have tried above work using pandas str.contains() and for loop, but given a large number of observations, it seems too slow and inefficient. My code looks like below.

```
num = []
for i in range(len(col1)):
    count = col2.str.contains(col1[i]).sum()
    num_replies.append(count)
```

Is there a time-efficient way to do this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` and `value_count`:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(df['col2'].value_counts()).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   index col1 col2  col3
0      0   aa   ji   2.0
1      1   bs   aa   1.0
2      2   qe   bs   0.0
3      3   gd   aa   0.0
```

Comment: This works way faster than Chaudhary's suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this :-

```
df['counts'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: list(df.col2.values).count(x))
```